# Suse Desktop on EC2/Azure

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, azure, opensuse, nomachine

I run a Suse Desktop Edition Instance on MS Azure, then installed NoMachine(NX) free ver 4.2.25, finally tried to connect from my local PC(OSX), but failed

Actually, I succeeded this with ubuntuServer14.04 with desktop environment, on Azure.

A reboot automatically launched a X gui Session.

However, when I tried with Suse Desktop Edition (+ lxde installed), after the reboot(or I probably don't have to since this is Desktop Edition) new GUI session seems to fail to launch.

On the connection, NX client says

> The server was unable to make the local display available or access to the local display is disabled.

So I tried So I tried [X Virtual Framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb):

```
 sudo zypper install -y xorg-x11-server

 export DISPLAY=:1  
 /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1920x1080x16 &
```

no luck.

Does someone know how to establish remote Xwindow connection of VM Suse?

Just note: I know x-server natively support remote connection, however especially my local client is MacOSX and don't want to run X, and I want to use NX for various reasons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, you don't need to have X actively running locally in any manner for NX sessions to succeed. I can't address your case in regards to MS Azure, but may I suggest going through the struggle of getting the old (and admittedly deprecated) freenx (not free NoMachine) to work? I have had success taking the rpm's from 0.7.3 and adapting them to modern Redhat or Debian based systems. Then it's usually just a matter of tweaking a bit and running 'nxsetup --install' to get it up and running. Also, if you can get your hands on the 3.5.X version of nxclient/nxnode (and nxserver if you wish), I think you'll have fewer complications. I've found NX 4.X to be cumbersome and problematic. Of note, you'll probably want to use "NoMachine login" rather than "System Login", and protocol "ssh" rather than "nx" (both were default in 3.5, but were swapped in 4.x).